# Tkinter Clear Optionmenu Menu Checkmark Next To Menu Item When Multiple OptionMenus

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

I create arbitrary amount of `ttk.Label`s and `ttk.OptionMenu`s in a `for` loop and store them in a dictionary named `entries` to later access them if needed.

**My problem is**, with multiple OptionMenus, when I select an option in one dropdown, a checkmark is set for all OptionMenus in the frame.

**Here's an example**. I selected `B` in the first dropdown, then went to the third dropdown, and before selecting anything, I see `B` with a checkmark next to it.

[image: OptionMenuSelectionCheckmark]

**I want** all OptionMenus to be independent of one-another and to not show a checkmark unless a selection has been made. In other words, is there a setting I can set so that making a selection in one dropdown doesn't set the same checkmark in all the other dropdowns?

I don't know if I should be looking in `dropdown['menu'].config().keys()` or `dir(dropdown['menu'])`.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine in this instance.

The code below reproduces the image and scenario above:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

entries = {}

for row in range(3):
  for column in range(2):
    index = (row, column)
    if column == 0:
      label = ttk.Label(root, text=repr(index), anchor=tk.E)
      label.grid(row=row, column=column)
    elif column == 1:
      var = tk.StringVar()
      options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
      var.set(options[0])
      dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var, options[0], *options)
      dropdown.config(width=15)
      dropdown.grid(row=row, column=column)

      entries[index] = [label, var, dropdown]

for index,objects in entries.items():
  print(index, type(objects[0]), type(objects[1]), type(objects[2]), type(objects[2]['menu']))

root.config(padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a bug with Tkinter, see Bryan's answer to my question for a workaround.

Comment: @Jkdc Thank you! You are right. Bryan's patch is exactly the answer I needed.